# Prometheus - overwrite $label.instance with custom value

Tags: prometheus

I'm new to Prometheus and a lot of things are not clear yet to me.

I would like to have a custom instance name for one of my target.

I have a `static_config` with a list of targets, something like this:

```
-   job_name: my_job
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - https://example-1.com/api/v1/status
      - https://example-2.com/api/v1/status
      - http://localhost:1234/v1/status
```

I tried the following config:

```
relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [__address__]
  regex: 'http://localhost:1234/v1/status'
  target_label: __instance__
  replacement: "myserver"
```

It doesn't work. I still have `$label.instance = http://localhost:1234/v1/status`

How can I overwrite `$label.instance` soi that `http://localhost:1234/v1/status` is replaced by `myserver` ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

After the comment of @markalex I also tried with the following config, without success:

```
relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [__address__]
  regex: 'http://localhost:1234/v1/status'
  target_label: instance
  replacement: "myserver"
```

Comment: It's not `__instance__` just `instance`.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried and it's still not working